# How to get error message in NativeScript 5?

Tags: nativescript

Could help me. How to get Error message in NativeScript 5 ?

```
try {
    devices = getDeviceList();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
```

This code write to console

> 'org.nativescript.b360124.serailport.NSSerialport$NSSerialPortException:
>   Device not found! JS:
>   org.nativescript.b360124.serailport.NSSerialport.getDeviceList(NSSerialport.java:66)
>   JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1120) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1000) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:987) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)

And how get message  "Device not found!", Thanks.

Comment: by the looks of it, the message is `org.nativescript.b360124.serailport.NSSerialport$NSSerialPortException: Device not found!`, so you would need to substring it, unless theres another peoperty of `error` which has a smaller error message

Comment: Hello, I add  in java  `class NSSerialPortException extends Exception {
        NSSerialPortException() {
        }

        NSSerialPortException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
            mymessage = msg;
        }

        public String mymessage;
    }`, but in nativescript `    try {
        devices = getDeviceList();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.mymessage);
      }` I get value `undefined`

Comment: Do you have sample where the issue can be reproduced. As far I checked, catch block seems to have access to the original java exception.

Comment: How, to get instance of  error If you have acces to the original java exeption?